# Unusable derived class std::map member

Tags: c++, inheritance, member

Please observe the following code:

Class Foo

```
class Foo:
{
   public:
     Foo();
     ~Foo();
}
```

Class C

```
class C
{
    public:
      C();
      ~C();
      void setA(A* a) { m_a = a; }
      A* getA() { return m_a; }

    private:
    A* m_a;
}
```

Abstract class A:

```
class A
{
public:
    // Constructor, Destructor
    A (C* c) : parent (c)
    virtual ~A(); 
    // Some RELEVANT pure abstract methods
    void addFoo(Foo* f, std::string& id) = 0;
    Foo* getFoo(std::string id)= 0;

protected:
    C* parent;
    std::map< std::string, Foo* > m_Foos;
};
```

In B.h

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    // Constructor, Destructor ...
    B(C* c);
    virtual ~B();
    // Definition of those pure RELEVANT methods
    virtual void addFoo(Foo* f, std::string& id);
    virtual Foo* getFoo(std::string id);        
};
```

In B.cpp

```
// Some methods implementation ...
B::B(C* c) : A(c) { }

Foo* B::getFoo(std::string id)
{
    return m_Foos[id];
}

B::setFoo( Foo* f, std::string& id )
{
    m_Foos[id] = f;
}
```

And then, in a different part of the code where everything was running smoothly until I decided to make m_Foos inheritable:

```
   C* c = new C();
   c->setA(new B(c));
```

This is executed beyond doubt before:

```
Foo* f = new Foo();
...
c->getA()->setFoo(f);
```

Program crashes when trying to access m_Foos inside setFoo. For some reason I can't yet understand, m_Foos is not correctly initialized in B (running m_Foos.size() for instance returns crazy values). Mind you that I get an error at runtime, not at compilation time.

Edit: it IS weird, since adding another protected member variable of type int in class A allows its modification and reading perfectly in B::setFoo()...

Comment: How are you declaring your instance of `B`

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), or it didn't happen.

Comment: `std::map<std::string id, Foo*> m_Foos;` -> `std::map<std::string, Foo*> m_Foos;`

Comment: As a matter of fact I pass (new B(C*)) to a function that expects a B*. One detail I've ommited is, the constructor of A takes a pointer to class C that is assigned in the constructor to its member variable of type pointer to C (m_pC), and that is assigned in the constructor of B like this: B::B(C*) : A(m_pC). I have ommited it because I don't see how it can be relevant, but I'm still learning so there's that.

Comment: The `B` instance is either not properly initialised or has been destroyed. Show the code that calls `setFoo` and how the `B` instance that responds to that call is created.

Comment: Again: keep throwing away the code until you get a minimal example that reproduces it. SSCCE or this question will get closed.

Comment: I may have just thrown away too much code in my previous example. This should be more SSCCE-like.

Comment: adding another int to class A fixing it: this tells me that you have something else corrupting memory, and putting the int there moved your important stuff out of the way so it just corrupted an unused int ... for now.  So the problem is definitely not in the class inheritance stuff, but in something else which is not correctly handling a pointer.  Not a big surprise with all the raw pointer use in this code.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your `B` is either a null pointer, hasn't *actually* been constructed, or was prematurely destructed.

Did you accidentally create it on the stack and store a pointer to it?

EDIT: Given that adding a member to `A` changes the behavior, somewhere in your code you're definitely getting into undefined behavior. We probably need to see more of your code to help more than general guesses.

Comment: No, the B is very much alive. I place some std::couts inside the function and they are coming pristine through the CLI. It's when it reaches the m_Foos[id] = f that all breaks apart. Mind you that other inherited members are actually working.

Comment: @roymcclure What did you print with `std::cout`? It doesn't depend on `this` by itself so it's quite possible that the undefined behavior allows `cout` to work and map access to fail.

Comment: But wouldn't calling a method on a pointer to an object that is not assigned crash the program?

Comment: @roymcclure Calling a method on an invalid pointer to object is undefined behavior and there are some systems in some cases where it wouldn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

The code (with some corrections) worked for me.  Since the crash went away when you added some other filler to A, I believe you have memory corruption.  Try setting the filler to a known value in A's constructor, and check the actual value when you get to where it would have crashed.

This won't actually help, other than verifying that memory corruption is happening elsewhere.